# OWL Carousel take load when slider are more than 300

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, owl-carousel

For my PhoneGap app I have used Owl jQuery slider.

And it was working perfectly fine. But now I have more than 300 slides in my slider. So due to that it makes my slide menu slow.

I am using jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Dont load all slides at once, paginate them.

Comment: Maybe try the lazyload plugin: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/lazyLoad.html

Comment: Thanks For suggestion of LazyLoad but i have already tried it.But Its not working.